# How do Poincare group act on Classical field, Quantum field operator, Field configuration states, Fock space states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hilbert-space, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

I will try to make each of my statement as clear as possible, if any of the statements are wrong prior to my question, please point them out:)

For simplicity, we work in free QFT with scalar field.

First we have Fock space, and the vacuum state defined to be the eigenstate of number operator with eigenvalue zero.

Second, to be accord with special relativity, we need to equip unitary irreducible representation of Poincare group to this infinite dimensional Fock space, let’s denote the action by $U(a,\lambda)$. So here I believe $U(a,\lambda)$ acts on states in Fock space.

Now, if we construct scalar field by promoting it from classical field of space time to quantum field as operator valued distribution, I believe by moral of quantum mechanics, i.e. by maintaining the same value for expectation value $<O>$, the unitary transformation on state could also be thought to act on observable adjointly, in this case I believe we could write $U^{-1}\phi(x) U$.

Now here comes my zeroth question, do we assume here the quantum field $\phi$ to be some observable? By this, I mean do we assume it to automatically be Hermitian? (Since I think it’s only true for Scalar field.)

My first question is: normally when we construct induced representation of Poincare group, we think of the underlying representation space to be smooth sections on the homogenous principle bundle $G/H$ where $G$ is Poincare group, and we always manipulate to make $H$ be $SL(2,C)$, so that the space of smooth sections is really classical field $\phi(x)$ on space time manifold. So, can I infer here directly that $U(a,\lambda)$ should act on classical field? Does this representation has the same physical meaning as the representation acting on Fock space state? What about the aforementioned adjoint action on quantum field operator? What are the relationship of the three?

My second question comes from my research on first question, I found the second Axiom of Wightman saying

- There exists a continuous unitary representation $U(a, \Lambda)$ of
  the restricted Poincare group such that $$ U(a, \Lambda) \phi(f)
     U^{-1}(a, \Lambda)=\phi\left(f_{(a, \Lambda)}\right), $$ where
  $f_{(a, \Lambda)}(x)=f\left(\Lambda^{-1}(x-a)\right)$; moreover $U(a,
     \Lambda) D \subset D$.

What’s going on here? I understand both sides of the equation should be an operator, after fixing a text function $f$, acing on states living in Fock space, but is it the same thing as whatwe usually mean by "specifying how (classical) field transform by Poincare group?" I have been completely lost here.

Further, what is the reason for it to be an “Axiom”? Does this mean we need to force this to be true in order to construct the representation $U$? But doesn’t the current induced representation of Poincare group we have in hand suffice to achieve this?

My third question is, what is the relationship between field configuration space and Fock space?